# Converting from Google Circle contacts to Google mail recipients

Tags: gmail, google-plus

I am a realtor and have 580 other realtors that I have downloaded their email addresses into a Google Circle. Now I am trying to email them a mass email for an Open House on this Sunday. I have placed my name in the To: window and wanted to put all other realtors in the BCC window. Can this be done? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts

You should see your circles as contacts in the left-hand sidebar. You can select a circle and then click All, then email using the icons above the list of names.

Comment: It's worth to remark that it's not possible to email at once 580 recipients from a Gmail consumer account unless a distribution list is used. The daily limit is 500. [Message bounced due to sending limit](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en)